# Test connection of azure SecretClient to azure KeyVault

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault

I was looking for api documentation for SecretClient but couldn't find a method that would test connection of a SecretClient to azure keyvault in python. Is there a way to check connection? My scenario is something like this:

```
token = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id="abc-def-ghi")
client = SecretClient(vault_url="https://<name>.vault.azure.net", credential=token)

# Check connection:
is_connected = client.check_connection()

# So if the connection is established continue
if is_connected:
    # do something
```

Comment: hello @robinhoodjr , `secretclient` doesn't have a method to check connection with keyvault.

Comment: I know. I looked at it's parent class too. Nothing there as well. Just wondering if I missed anything and someone knew how-to.

Answer (score 0):

The method `SecretClient().get_secret()` throws an exception if there is a problem with the login or the secret doesn't exist in the vault.

I use `DefaultAzureCredential` to get the token automatically from AZ CLI. Be sure to run `az login` in the terminal to initialize the AZ_CLI credentials for a system that doesn't use AZ managed identity. Here is a working example:

You can create a secret `AZ_KV_KEYNAME_TEST` in the vault for the test.

```
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

def check_connection(): 
        AZ_KV_KEYNAME_TEST = "AZ_KV_KEYNAME_TEST" 
        KVUri = "https://<name>.vault.azure.net"
        credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
        client = SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential)
        try:
            retrieved_secret = client.get_secret(AZ_KV_KEYNAME_TEST)
            print("Success")
            return True
        except Exception as E:
            print(str(E))
            return False

if check_connection():
    #code goes here ..
```

Comment: Did you post the complete code example? It appears to be truncated.